# WordPress Shopping Cart - Traditional Gift cards

Tags: wordpress, shopping-cart

My client is a restaurant and the only product they sell online is a traditional giftcard.  The orders are manually fulfilled by the admin staff at the restaurant and a real, plastic giftcard is mailed to the recipient.

My store needs to allow selection of the single product, selection of $ amount, selection of quantity.
Also needs a "FROM", "TO", "MESSAGE", "Shipping Info"

I've evaluated WPEasyCart and WooCommerce, but neither are configurable to this degree.  Any suggestions on other plugins that can handle this scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write your own cart or have someone write one for you. Most carts are overly complicated for what you require.

Comment: Alternatively you could use ContactForm7 with PayPal integration.